# Nodejs Passport no puedo imprimir por consola - Status 302

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, passport

Estoy recibiendo datos de un post con **passport** en Nodejs, mi terminal dice que si recibe el post, pero me manda un status 302, aunque si me meanda a donde estoy manejando el error, no obstante antes debería imprime consola mis datos de request. Pero no lo hace, alguien pordía orientarme? Gracias.

```js
//router

router.post('/signin', (req, res, next) => {
    try{
    passport.authenticate('local.signin',{
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/signin',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req,res,next);
}catch(e){
    console.log(e)
}
});

//passport

passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'user',
  passwordField: 'pass',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, async(req, user, pass, done) => {

    try{
    console.log(req.body);
    const result = await pool.query('select * from users where name = ?',[user]);
    console.log(result.rows.length);
        if(isNaN(result.rows.length) ||  null(result.rows.lengt)){
            throw new Error('no se hace query'); 
        }

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    } 
    
    return result;
}));
```

```html
<form action="/signin" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="">
      <label for="UserName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label card-text">Nombre</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control " placeholder="NombreEjemplo" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="">
      <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label card-text">Password</label><br>
      <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control " placeholder="tucontraseña123" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row p5">
    <input class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" value="try">
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué te devuelve `result.rows.length`? Has verificado eso? Sabes si en realidad te devuelve algo? Como usas una función `async` es necesario que manejes los errores tú mismo. Verifica que result no sea `null` o `undefined`.

Comment: @MauricioContreras estoy haciendo algunos cambios y ando  checando como manejar los errores.

Comment: Ok, te devuelve algo `result.rows.length`? o `result.rows`?

Comment: Nada de nada ya intenté intervenir tambien el passport.authenticate, pero no me tira nada, no obstante si cambio la failureRedirect si me manda a donde lo cambie, ahora subo mis cambios

Comment: Intenta usar una función no asíncrona, luego pasas un callback a tu llamada a `pool.query()` y allí capturas usando `then` y `catch(err)`. Tal vez la promesa de `pool.query()` tenga un problema.

Comment: @MauricioContreras listo ya está, es una burrada de mi parte, usernameField: 'name', no user, porque el form manda name, gracias por tu tiempo, eres un buenaso. Si quieres te doy la respuesta por tu tiempo. Y result.rows.length sale undefined

Comment: Perfecto, al menos no era nada oscuro, siempre es un error nuestro. Y `pool.query.rows` da undefined porque simplemente no retorna ningún registro en la consulta, y era porque pasabas el parámetro equivocado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qué te devuelve `result.rows.length`? Has verificado eso? Sabes si en realidad te devuelve algo? Como usas una función `async` es necesario que manejes los errores tú mismo. Verifica que `result` no sea `null` o `undefined`.